# How to split interfaces whether to have one action per interface or grouping similar actions per interface?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, refactoring, solid-principles

I read about *Dependence Inversion Principle* and have seen example as below

There is an interface called `IBird` as below

```
interface IBird
{
    public void Eat();
    public void Walk();
    public void Fly();
}
```

`Pigeon` class is derived as below from the interface and pigeon does all the actions.

```
class Pigeon : IBird
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pigeon can eat");
    }

    public void Walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pigeon can walk");
    }

    public void Fly()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pigeon can fly");
    }
}
```

When I derive `Ostrich` then the `Fly` method won't be applicable since it can't fly.

Hence the interfaces has been created as below to address this issue.

```
interface IEat { }

interface IWalk { }

interface IFly { }
```

And the `Ostrich` and `Pigeon` classes will be derived as below:

```
class Ostrich : IEat, IWalk 
{
}

class Pigeon : IEat, IWalk, IFly
{
}
```

I have a clarification as below.

Could we make interfaces as below to address this issue.

```
interface IFlyingBirds
{
    public void Eat();
    public void Walk();
    public void Fly();
}
```

For flightless birds I created a separate interface.

```
interface IFlightlessBirds
{
    public void Eat();
    public void Walk();
}
```

And the `Pigeon` and `Ostrich` classes will be derived as below:

```
class Pigeon : IFlyingBirds
{
}

class Ostrich : IFlightlessBirds
{
}
```

Is there something wrong in this approach?

Please throw some light on this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

Comment: That seems alright to me. I don't like interfaces for this sort of thing and prefer multiple inheritance, or depending on the case the aggregation and the composition. But otherwise it's clean for me. Nothing wrong, on the contrary, except that it's looking for lice and spagetti if you have a short code that does little. But for a big app, it's ok to do that like that and you have a good abstraction. Thus therefore the only primordial, main, important and major question is: why do you need interfaces to design your domain and acheive goals? And do you have the time and the money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line of those SOLID principles, is to make the code more understandable, easy to maintain, and easy to scale.

Each solution would work, but think, does it make sense for your code to split those behaviors into two different interfaces?

Or maybe it would be better to create these interfaces:

```
public interface IBird
{
    public void Eat();
    public void Walk();
}

public interface IFlyingBird : IBird
{
    public void Fly();
}
```

Whatever makes sense better for your code.

Take note that the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) tells us to split our behavior as much as possible so that each entity is declared only with what it needs.

Meaning if in one place you have an `Eagle` class and you know you will never have to use the `Walk()` method for it, so why should you declare it with it?

That's a case where these declarations are more reasonable:

```
interface IEat
{
}

interface IWalk
{
}

interface IFly
{
}
```